# How to add selected index of a combobox to a column in a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, combobox

I have found variations of this, but nothing that fixed the problem. So here it goes:

I am using Winforms. I have a combobox and a listview with 3 columns. The user can either select an existing value from the combobox or add their own value through a textbox and a button. This all works okay.

Here is where I run into problems:
I want the user to be able to select a value, in this case a category, from the combobox and display that in the listview under the "Category" column.

I am in the process of teaching myself C#, this is day 2 so bear with me please.

My listview code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Calls the function that adds properties to the listview
        PopulateListView();
        btnEditDesiredEnd.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        btnDeposit.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

    }

    public void PopulateListView()
    {
        //Listview Properties:
        //Listview Details 
        lstView.View = View.Details;
        //Allow user to edit labels
        lstView.LabelEdit = true;
        //Allow user to change column order
        lstView.AllowColumnReorder = true;
        //Display checkboxes
        //lstView.CheckBoxes = true;
        //Display gridlines
        lstView.GridLines = true;
        //Allows user to select entire row
        lstView.FullRowSelect = true;


        //Create columns, width of -2 indicates auto-size
        lstView.Columns.Add("Transaction", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lstView.Columns.Add("Category", 130, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lstView.Columns.Add("Description", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        //Add listview as a control
        this.Controls.Add(lstView);
    }
```

And here is the button that should add all the user inputs to the listview. The only line that does not work is the last line.

It gives me the following error: **Cannot assign 'Add' because it is a 'method group'**.

```
private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstView.View = View.Details;

        ListViewItem lvwItem = lstView.Items.Add(txtDeposit.Text);
        lvwItem.SubItems.Add(txtWithdraw.Text);
        lvwItem.SubItems.Add(txtDescription.Text);

        txtDeposit.Clear();
        txtWithdraw.Clear();
        txtDescription.Clear();

        btnDeposit.Enabled = false;
        btnDeposit.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

        lstView.Items.Add = cboCategory.SelectedIndex;

    }
```

**EDIT: Here is the working code.. (cboCategory is the combobox)**

```
private void btnDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstView.View = View.Details;
        ListViewItem lvwItem = lstView.Items.Add(txtDeposit.Text);
        if (cboCategory.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(cboCategory.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
        lvwItem.SubItems.Add(txtDescription.Text);
```

Comment: What you're trying to do with this line `lstView.Items.Add = cboCategory.SelectedIndex;`?

Comment: Erroneously attempting to add the selected index of the combo box to the "Category" column of the listview

Comment: So you need selected text to be added in `ListView` ?

Comment: The items in the two controls bothe are called _Items_ but they are __not compatible__. One is a [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the other an [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can assign the textual representation of a selected ComboBox item like this: `lvwItem.Items.Add( cboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() );`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that's exactly right.

Comment: @TaW now I have lvw.SubItems.Add(cboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString()); As close as I have gotten, but now I am getting a NulReferenceException was unhandled error "check to determine if the object is null before calling the method"

Comment: You'll need to check that there actually __is__ a value selected. Insert `if (cboCategory.SelectedValue != null)` before the `Add`

Comment: No more errors, but nothing shows up. Sorry if I'm being a nuisance, is this right? if (cboCategory.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                lvwItem.SubItems.Add(cboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString());
            } @TaW

Comment: I'm sorry, I got that wrong. You need to use `SelectedItem`not `SelectedValue`. The latter is only for bound Controls where the Value member points into a data source. The rest of your code is ok, just those two changes!

Comment: Ah perfect, it finally works!! Thanks so much you rock @TaW !

Answer (score 1):

The .Add is a method so it needs to be called like a method.

```
lstView.Items.Add("Adding this string to the list view");
```

However I don't know what cboCategory is so I cant advise on what youre trying to add.

Comment: cboCategory is the combo box! Sorry should have specified

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Sriram above this line is completely wrong, well actually we don't know what your cboCategory holds either.

```
lstView.Items.Add = cboCategory.SelectedIndex;
```

Sure you are not supposed to do a:

```
lstView.Items.Add(lvwItem);
```

And/Or...

```
var selectedValue = lstView.Items.FirstOrDefault( c=>whateversearchparameters here);
if( selectedValue!=null )
      SelectAndStuffHere();
```

Bit hard to tell without knowing more :)

But hope it helps,

Cheers

Stian